# PhySim Oscilloscope does not show any output when using DC components?

Tags: communication, simulator

I have recently starting using the communication simulator PhySim. When I use only Dc components in my modules, PhySim executes but the in built software oscilloscope does not show any output. How do I resolve this problem? Does I need to change anything in config file ? Or should the source C code be changed ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

PhySim requires the use of at least one ac component for proper working of the communication system blocks. The sampling rate is determined by the frequency of the blocks commented. If only DC components are chosen, then there is nothing to quantize since the value will remain same throughout. Since the frequency of Dc is zero, so the parameter passed for sampling time difference is 1/0 = INF in C. So , the sampling does not take place and so the Output files are empty.  Simple fix – Use the following for working worth DC –  ((Signal Source + DC)- Signal Source )-> Pass it to the
modules in the next stage.